# How to calculate the median from a set of data where some of the data is sampled over unequal intervals of time?

Tags: median, extrapolation

Suppose you are measuring how much money you spend each calendar week (Monday to Sunday) over the course of March 2024 and the results are as follows:

| Date range | Money spent ($) |
| --- | --- |
| 03/01 to 03/03 | 0 |
| 03/04 to 03/10 | 35 |
| 03/11 to 03/17 | 95 |
| 03/18 to 03/24 | 50 |
| 03/25 to 03/31 | 85 |

Our sorted data set would be {0, 35, 50, 85, 95}, and a simple median calculation would yield $50.

Notice that all of the intervals are a full calendar week except for the first one, which is only 3 days (Friday to Sunday). Including a partial calendar week in this calculation could bias the "median" toward a lower value, such that the actual possibility of money spent during a given calendar week being greater than $75 exceeds 50% likelihood. This contradicts the definition of the median, since a median is supposed to represent the number that is less than or equal to 50% of the data set and greater than or equal to 50% of the data set. This bias would be even more pronounced in months that start *and* end with partial calendar weeks.

Assuming that we cannot determine or estimate spending patterns throughout the course of a calendar week, is there some meaningful way that we can calculate a median *without excluding* the money spent from 03/01 to 03/03 *and without including* the money spent from 02/26 to 02/29?

I imagine the ideal solution would be to rework the span of each interval or the entire data collection period such that some multiple of the former fits evenly into the latter, but for the sake of this problem, assume that we want to know (or meaningfully estimate) the median dollars spent per calendar week for March 2024.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible takes and I think you've got to decide depending on your larger context. I don't really follow quite what is possible or impossible in the real version of this problem, if there is one, so these comments won't have equal force for you: the point of any thread is that other people may have similar questions even if their question is not identical to yours.

1. Ignore incomplete weeks and take median over complete weeks, here (50 + 85)/2.
2. Multiply up incomplete weeks by 7 / #days and then take the median.
3. Why care about medians? Medians are volatile for this purpose as much hinges on 1 and 2 above and whether you are using 3 or 4 or even 5 data points. Means are linked to totals, which have obvious but important meaning for expenditure. (My bank has no interest (pun intended) in median inputs or outputs, but every interest in totals.) Use monthly total and divide by #days in month if needed, and then also multiply by 7 to get equivalent for all weeks in a month if needed.
4. Why care about months? Just work with weeks regardless of whether they span months (or years!).
5. Why care about weeks? Weekly values are volatile any way. Just work with months (and worry a little about length of month, incidence of special days, etc.).

I doubt that's a complete list. A good answer depends much more on the practicalities of what you want to do with these summaries than on any deep principles.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I agree that this problem is primarily dependent on the context and the purpose such a statistic is meant to serve. I will probably end up shifting the week intervals to align with the 1st day of the month (that way there is only a maximum of 1 partial week) and then discard the partial week.